# How can I move a div on scroll?

Tags: javascript, vertical-scrolling, onscroll

I have to move a div when the the user scrolls, but need to use pure JavaScript.

`position: fixed;` will not work with the layout. The div's original position is relative to something else. Is there a simple implementation using an event like `onscroll`, to detect how many pixels the page moved up or down, and change the position of the div accordingly?

The div only needs to move vertically. So if I can detect how many pixels the page has moved I can just add or subtract that to the location of the div.

Comment: So what you have by now is... (this is where you paste a code snippet you've done so far)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
window.onscroll = function (e) {
  var vertical_position = 0;
  if (pageYOffset)//usual
    vertical_position = pageYOffset;
  else if (document.documentElement.clientHeight)//ie
    vertical_position = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  else if (document.body)//ie quirks
    vertical_position = document.body.scrollTop;

  var your_div = document.getElementById('some_div');
  your_div.style.top = (vertical_position + 200) + 'px';//200 is arbitrary.. just to show you could now position it how you want
}
```

Comment: You're awesome:-) that worked perfectly in every browser I tried it in. Thank you so much for helping me.

Comment: @Jake First of all it has to be  your_div.style.top (style is missing in your code) isn`t? And also this moves a div only once and not as we scroll. Please correct me if I`m wrong!

Comment: This code seems to work great, I'm curious though, why no curly brackets?