# jQuery Moving a div with page scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to move a div based on page scroll, I've already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616335/moving-div-with-scroll) question but it's based on pure javascript.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/krish7878/a2tkorno/6/) I made, here's what I [want](http://isotopethemes.com/slider-test/).

Here's the code:

HTML:

```
<div class="outer-container">
    <div class="inner-container">
        <div class="slider-one slide" style="background-image:url('http://208.131.135.54/~imacre17/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/homeslide1a.png'); height: 100%; background-size: cover;" class="slider-background-image' ">
            <div class="slide-inner-container">
                <div class="slider-content">
                    <h4>The Course</h4>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
                    </p>
                </div>
                <!-- /.slider-content -->
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.slide-inner-container -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.slide -->
        <div class="slider-one slide" style="background-image:url('http://208.131.135.54/~imacre17/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/2-Home-membership.jpg'); height: 100%; background-size: cover;" class="slider-background-image' ">
            <div class="slide-inner-container">
                <!-- More content here soon -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.slide-inner-container -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.slide -->
        <div class="slider-one slide" style="background-image:url('http://208.131.135.54/~imacre17/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/2-Home-special-events.jpg'); height: 100%; background-size: cover;" class="slider-background-image' ">
            <div class="slide-inner-container">
                <!-- More content here soon -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.slide-inner-container -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.slide -->
        <div class="slider-one slide" style="background-image:url('http://208.131.135.54/~imacre17/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/CORKHome-_position4.jpg'); height: 100%; background-size: cover;" class="slider-background-image' ">
            <div class="slide-inner-container">
                <!-- More content here soon -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.slide-inner-container -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.slide -->


    </div>
    <!-- /.inner-container -->
</div>
<!-- /.outer-container -->
```

I want the div with class `'.slider-content'` to move on page scroll just like the [reference link](http://isotopethemes.com/slider-test/)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to script this yourself?

Comment: I did, I'll update the question with my attempt but I'm not familiar on pageYOffset

Comment: you have semicolons `;` after each css property in you jquery. there is no need for them, in fact, you should not have them at all. http://jsfiddle.net/yak613/657mm7Lz/

Comment: @yak613: Sorry, I knew that before and corrected them too but put posted the old link, thanks for pointing out through.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use **skrollr.js**

Check the demo of this [website](https://ihatetomatoes.net/how-to-create-a-parallax-scrolling-website/) 
It is similar to what you want

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but it might make things complicated, dealing with an other framework. Custom code would be the most effective way, thank you for your answer though.

Answer (score 0):

I think using "position:fixed;" is the easiest way. I changed it and it works for me.

Line 23:

```
.slider-content{
    position: fixed;
    //...
}
```

And then you can set the position (left, top, ...) to make it look like in the example that you shared.

Comment: thank you but I want the div to disappear after it crosses the parent div which is not possible with position: fixed

Comment: not even with this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218927/z-index-not-working-with-fixed-positioning

Comment: using z-index with fixed position seems to be an alternative, let me try that, if it works it will be a far simpler solution.